# How to make macbook pro use a 16:9 aspect ratio?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

How can I force my screen to use a 16:9 aspect ratio? I don't mind seeing black bars above and beneath the screen content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RDM](https://github.com/avibrazil/RDM) to set a custom resolution such as 1920×1080.

Comment: One thing I've noticed with this is that the ... pixel density? I don't know the right term ... seems lower. E.g. it looks like it is a lower resolution than it used to be.